# Qual a vantagem de utilizar include de array vs arquivo de configuração?

Tags: php, array, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

Tenho observado alguns códigos onde o programador faz o seguinte:

```
/** Arquivo A.php */
return array('databaseName' => 'bancoTeste', 'port' => 5208);
```

---

```
/** Arquivo B.php */
$configs = include("A.php");
// Acesso as $configs
echo $configs['databaseName'];
```

Este pequeno trecho de código demonstra que a intenção é ter as configurações armazenadas em um arquivo PHP e extrai-las através de `include`. Um outro método mais comum é utilizar um arquivo de configuração plano (`.ini` por exemplo) e carregá-lo via fopen, etc.

1 - Qual a vantagem e desvantagem de cada método?

2 - Existe alguma melhoria de performance de um método sob o outro?

Comment: O `Laravel` tem muito isso!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em resposta a sua dúvida podemos citar várias vantagens e desvantagens em cada tipo de arquivo de configuração em array por exemplo pode-se criar estruturas de dados mais complexas do que usando INI, mas em contrapartida o INI é mais legível que um array.

Mas basicamente o uso vai do gosto/necessidade da solução que você esta implementando, alguns dos formatos de configuração que posso citar é:

- INI
- Array
- JSON
- XML
- YAML

Em questão de performance o Array tem vantagem por ser um tipo nativo composto do PHP. Mas como disse nada impede que você use outro método/formato para configurar sua aplicação.

O framework Symfony2 por exemplo permite fazer configurações por YAML, mas nem por isso ele deixa a aplicação lenta, já que ele cria um arquivo de cache em formato Array com essa configuração. (http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/config/introduction.html)

Pode ver um benchmark aqui: http://konrness.com/php5/zend_config-benchmark-json-array-ini-xml-yaml/

--

Update:

Eu já tive dúvidas também em qual tipo de formato de configuração usar e achei a referência que tomei como base na época (https://web.archive.org/web/20120826210434/http://www.zyxist.com/pokaz.php/formaty_danych_benchmark)

Sendo que a ordem do mais rápido para o mais lento é:

- Array serializado
- script PHP
- INI
- XML
- YAML

Mas nada impede de usar um formato mais legível para sua configuração (YAML) e usar a estratégia de transformar em um array.

Comment: Muito boa a explicação do `Symphony` :). Isso é para tirar totalmente o preconceito de usar `yaml`

Answer (score 4):

Não há uma melhora de performance que realmente faça diferença. Se medir é provável, mas não é certo, que tenha alguma vantagem para um lado ou outro. Se realmente quiser saber faça um teste de *benchmark*. Não o farei porque não vale a pena nem mesmo sendo simples de fazer. Não importa, não muda nada em programa algum.

Note que a forma como o arquivo está organizado, tanto em uma forma como a outra, e a forma que vai recuperar esses dados pode fazer mais diferença. Uma comparação para entender: O que é mais rápido, acessar o disco ou acessar a memória? Depende de como cada acesso é feito. É possível fazer um algoritmo tão ruim em memória que fique mais lento que acessar os mesmos dados em disco. É um exemplo extremo mas é possível. A moral da estória é que algoritmos são mais importantes.

Em geral em outras linguagens eu diria que configurar por uma estrutura de dados no próprio código poderia ser melhor por não ter a dependência de um arquivo externo que pode ser modificado por alguém, até mesmo desaparecer. E teria a vantagem de permitir que alguém altere as configurações pelo arquivo externo. Mas em PHP as configurações já estão em arquivo externo que podem ser modificados.

O que eu posso ver de diferente e isto é importante é que se você apenas retorna uma configuração e tem todas elas em um arquivo central (não importa o formato e como ele é carregado) muda a organização.

Em geral eu ficaria com um arquivo central mas depende do caso. Ter um arquivo central carregado pode deixar ligeiramente mais lento porque carregará configurações que ele não precisa naquele momento. Mas isto é mínimo e não fará diferente. É puramente por razões organizacionais. Imagine ter que procurar por configurações por toda a aplicação. Mas não digo que não possa haver casos que descentralizar seja positivo, só não consigo ver um facilmente.

Fora isto, a não ser que eu veja uma justificativa explícita, eu diria que é questão de estilo.

Mas note que o primeiro caso **pode** não ser considerado exatamente configuração. Não vi um caso concreto mas pode ser apenas uma informação necessária para alguma coisa pontual. Apesar da propriedade chamar `config` não significa que ela seja efetivamente uma configuração como outras existentes. Pode haver um motivo semântico para fazer diferente. Pode haver a necessidade, no caso concreto, de deixar claro que ali precisa ser feito isolado de outras configurações.

Answer (score 3):

1 - Qual a vantagem e desavantagem de cada método?

A vantagem da primeira abordagem é a simplicidade: você não precisa abrir o resource do arquivo, ler os dados, converter para array, fechar para utilizar do seu conteúdo.

Por outro lado, utilizar arquivos `.ini` fica mais claro para um administrador de sistema por exemplo que aquele arquivo específico se refere a um tipo de configuração.

2 - Existe alguma melhoria de performance de um método sob o outro?

Nada significativo, mas com a primeira abordagem o PHP pode armazenar o arquivo na memória através do [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.opcache.php), tornando o carregamento nas requisições seguintes mais rápida.

No caso de utilizar um `fopen` simples, a cada requisição teremos que acessar o disco, podendo causar gargalos.

Comment: Gostei de sua resposta, portanto estou dando +1 por colaborar com a pergunta.