# Vantagens e desvantagens de usar arquivos INI

Tags: php, ini

Poderiam me dizer as possíveis vantagens e desvantagens em usar um arquivo `.INI` para fazer a configuração de uma aplicação? Preferencialmente, aplicações PHP.

Comment: Geralmente é bastante utilizado para não precisar criar mais um executável com uma configuração diferente diretamente na aplicação, assim na aplicação é apenas apontado o caminho do arquivo .INI e as mudanças podem ser feitas diretamente neste arquivo, principalmente se tratando de banco de dados, configuração específica para uma determinada empresa, ou outro parâmetro qualquer que precisa fazer uma operação diferente em um executável ou outro.

Comment: A principal vantagem é a simplicidade pois é uma operação simples em um arquivo texto , a desvantagem é que uma configuração errada podecser feita , basta ter acesso ao arquivo texto.

Comment: É uma aplicação php, é mais recomendável fazer em INI ou PHP (Esse arquivo ficaria com as config da database)

Comment: Sua pergunta tem 2 votos para fechar como "principalmente baseada em opiniões" (e terá 3 contando com o meu), afinal de contas o que João acha importante para usar INI no PHP pode ser algo que o Pedro não aprecie. Ou algo que a Maria considere um motivo forte para não usar os arquivos INI, a Paula pode achar que não há nada de errado. No final, tudo depende de circunstâncias específicas da sua aplicação e os requisitos envolvidos, circunstâncias e requisitos tais que você não descreveu.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50275/qual-a-vantagem-de-utilizar-include-de-array-vs-arquivo-de-configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 1):

**Arquivos INI** são considerados um standard. Um "padrão informal" para arquivos de configuração para software. *Arquivos INI* são arquivos de texto simples, com uma estrutura básica composta por secções, propriedades e valores.

Só vejo vantagens na sua utilização, mas irá sempre depender das necessidades de um projeto.

Não acho muito relevante em pequenos projetos. Mas quando trabalhamos projetos em equipe ou se existir a necessidade de outros poderem parametrizar é importante ter um standard pois simplifica e muito.

Destacaria que é totalmente independente do software, legível e simples de analisar, por isso é um formato utilizável para arquivos de configuração até com algum grau de complexidade.